# I have a code to simulate a data but when I check the results of the output results are not matching

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

for data set Y I have inputted mean as 10 but when I try to check the mean after creating the data set its giving me mean as 0.09038462 could I know the reason plz

```
set.seed(22)
x   <- seq(5,15,length=1000)
y   <- dnorm(x,mean=10, sd=3)

mean(y)
```

Comment: `dnorm` returns the probabllyt distribution.  You can also check [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157662/rnorm-vs-dnorm-in-r/157667) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156883/difference-between-density-and-probability)